# Steam API CSGo Get All Item Categories

Tags: api, steam, steam-web-api, steambot

I'm trying to find API method for Steam CSGO, which I can use to retreive all:

- weapon categories;
- wear;
- exterior;
- phase;
- grade.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Found this link to a reddit post. Mabye it helps you? https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamBot/comments/3lkrgf/i_am_trying_to_figure_this_out_as_well/cv7jsfc/

Comment: @pascalzoet, unfortunately, this link didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to retrieve the "Phase" of a item you would need to retrieve paintindex and check what "phase" said paintindex is.

to get the wear value, exterior etc you can simply use the "[globaloffensive](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-globaloffensive)" npm module and then call the "inspectItem" function with the inspect_url for the item you want to get data for.

```
csgo.inspectItem("URL",function(item) {
    let paintindex = item.paintindex; // ITEMS paintindex, used to identify phase...
    let wear = item.paintwear; // "FLOAT VALUE".
    let quality = item.quality;
    //...
});
```

If you need a database for the "paintindex" you could check [metjm.net](http://metjm.net/database/).

Regards

Comment: Thank you, nice answer. It really helpfull.